# Is there something html "for" attribute event flag?

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events

How to I know event occurred by "for" attribute?

Is there something like flag?

I make sample html. I test it in Chrome.

```
    <html>
    <head>
        <script>
         var div1 = document.getElementById("div1");
        
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
            <div id="div1" style="relatvie;width:500px;height:200px" onclick="alert(5)">
    <input type="checkbox" id="checktest"></input><label for="checktest">12345</label>
    </div>
    </body>

    </html>
```

In this case, if you click label then alert is occurred twice.

I want to single alert.

Comment: Insufficient explanation to know what this question actually means.  Question should include relevant sample HTML or Javascript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you mean something like this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dhoerster/dYVYK/)?

I added an id attribute to the label and then wired up a click event handler to it via jQuery.  It may not be per spec, but it seems to work.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){
      $("#phoneLbl").click(function(e){
          alert('here');
      });
  });
</script>
<label id="phoneLbl" for="phone">Phone</label><input id="phone" type="text" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to assume you mean the HTMLLabelElement's `for` attribute. This attribute is used to link a label to a particular input:

```
<label for="phone">Phone #:</label><input id="phone">
```

There are no events associated with this attribute; you cannot attach an event handler to it. It is simply an attribute of the label element.

Comment: Does label's for attribute work on the input's name attribute or the id attribute?

Comment: @bozdoz good catch; that should be id. edited.